Optimization of affine invariant metric
Notations:

$\theta$: Rotation angle
$s$: Scale factor
$t = (t_x, t_y)$: Translation vector
$R(\theta) = \begin{bmatrix} \cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta \end{bmatrix}$: Rotation matrix
$S_X, S_Y$: SPD matrix.

Transformation:
The transformation $T$ applied to a point $p$ is defined as:
$T(p; s, \theta, t) = sR(\theta)p + t$
1. Affine-Invariant Distance between SPD Matrices:
The affine-invariant distance is defined as:
$d_{SPD}(S_X, S_Y(s, \theta, t)) = \|\log(S_X^{-1/2} S_Y(s, \theta, t) S_X^{-1/2})\|_F$
where $\log(\cdot)$ is the matrix logarithm, and $\|\cdot\|_F$ is the Frobenius norm.
Objective Function:
The complete objective function is a weighted sum of these two components:
$f(s, \theta, t) =  \cdot d_{SPD}(S_X, S_Y(s, \theta, t))$
Optimization Problem:
Our goal is to find the optimal transformation parameters that minimize this objective function:
$\min_{s, \theta, t} f(s, \theta, t)$
Can anyone suggest me the way to solve this optimization problem, any such method or anything will be most helpful. Thanks!

What about your ideas ?

Actually, I am not familiar with this area much! I tried to apply the gradient descent but the answer was not satisfactory!
